# How to fix no javabridge no module error? how to find and set jdk path?

Tags: java, python, ssh, xserver, java-bridge-method

I am trying to install javabridge to my rental server using ssh.
Python, jdk (app-engine-java ), numpy, pandas, python-weka-wrapper are installed but
Pip install javabridge 
gives me errors.

I tried to set up the path
but the installation still error.

pip install javabridge

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. 
>   Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. > A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
>   Collecting javabridge
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/a0/c59bccabed99b1d4ac68166c59c679b375bfca75b78688b52c541b711578/javabridge-1.0.18.tar.gz
>
> ```
> ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>      ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>  File "/tmp/pip-install-RqqZMr/javabridge/setup.py", line 402, in 
> <module>
>    ext_modules=ext_modules(),
> ```
>
> when I typed
>   which java
>
> ```
>  ~/.linuxbrew/bin/java
> ```
>
> .bash_profile
>
> ```
>   $HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH
> # Get the aliases and functions
> if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
>         . ~/.bashrc
> fi
>
> # User specific environment and startup programs
>
> PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH
>
> EXPORT eval "$(pyenv init -)"
>
> export PYTHON_PATH="$PATH:/home/cantik/.linuxbrew/lib/python2.7"
> export JAVA_PATH="/home/cantik/.linuxbrew/bin/java"
> echo ${JAVA_HOME}
>
> export HOMEBREW_TEMP=~/tmp PATH=~/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
>
> export LDFLAGS="-L/home/cantik/.linuxbrew/opt/isl@0.18/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/cantik/.linuxbrew/opt/isl@0.18/include"
> ~
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Try using `export JAVA_HOME=/home/cantik/.linuxbrew`

Comment: Hi, I changed it but it's still same error

Comment: Does `javac` exist? javabridge requires the Java header files to be present (part of a JDK). Run `which javac`.